# Are there any well-known quantitative approaches to evaluate a particular design whether it satisfies or violates the SOLID design principles?

Tags: design-patterns, frameworks, object-oriented-design, solid, software-evaluation

I designed an application framework by considering the SOLID design principles and supported by design patterns. However, I wonder if there are any automated tools or well-known approaches to evaluate whether the SOLID design principles are satisfied or violated in the proposed design?

Comment: By definition that is impossible, since one of the principles of SOLID design is to have one purpose for each class.  How would you go about determining how many purposes a class has?  Perhaps you could make some sort of conclusions about the other principles, but definitely not all are possible.

Comment: In the future, please do not cross-post questions between Stack Exchange sites. This question belongs on Programmers, where it is on-topic. If you ask a question on the wrong site, flag it for moderator review and request a migration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code) and of [What are useful metrics for source code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/27686/what-are-useful-metrics-for-source-code)

Answer (score 2):

At least the S, O, and L in SOLID stand for semantic principles - one has to *understand* what the code does and what its purpose is to validate those things. I am pretty sure A.I. research has not gotten so far (at least, not yet) to make a computer really understand the meaning of programs. So don't expect anything automatic nowadays.

But you have also asked for "well-known approaches" - well, there is one very well-known approach, it is called "code review by an expert" and I am pretty sure you have heard of it ;-) So the best suggestion I can give you is to post some parts of your code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and discuss it there.

Comment: +1, that they're semantic principles is the root of the problem here, well said.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it were possible, I think the effort might be wasted. What you can do is measure the impact of adherence to the principles has on the maintainability of your code. Coupling, cohesion, and cyclomatic complexity can all be measured by static analysis tools.

Also, if you're using .NET, you might be able to leverage StyleCop to create rules for adherence to certain guidelines. Again that might be more effort than it's worth. Either way, it can't hurt to use it.